# Haskell Error: No instance for (Num [[a0]] arising from a use of `it`

Tags: haskell

I'm stuck on an error which is given when I test this function:

```
maxWeight n wc f =
let ps (x:xs) = case x of 
    [] -> [[]]
    otherwise -> ps xs ++ map (x:) (ps xs)
in maximum $ filter (<wc) $ map sum $ ps $ map f [1..n]
```

This is the full error:

```
No instance for (Num [[a0]]) arising from a use of `it`
In a statement of an interactive GHCi command: print it
```

I'm testing the function by calling it in GHCi with

```
maxWeight 5 10 (\i -> i + 1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find it difficult to fathom what your function (and the helper `ps`)  is supposed to do (this usually helps to get better answers... :-) but it looks like you are confusing two idioms in your definition of `ps`

You can write

```
ps y = case y of
  [] -> [[]]
  (x:xs) -> ps xs ++ map (x:) (ps xs)
```

or just

```
ps [] = [[]]
ps (x:xs) = ps xs ++ map (x:) (ps xs)
```

but as it stands now, the definition of `ps` is missing a base case (what is `ps []`?)

With this out of the way, the definition compiles, and `maxWeight 5 10 (\i -> i + 1)` yields `9`

Comment: Oh I see, I had assumed that matching the first element being an empty list is the same as matching the entire input being an empty list

Comment: An empty  list has no first element,  but `[[]]` *does* have an empty list as it s first element. So for the compiler, your `ps` works on lists of lists, and hence returns lists of lists of lists. When you sum these, you are treating lists of lists as if they were numbers, which is (in ordinary English) what the error messeage says.